# jQuery datetime to_string (iOS html5 datetime picker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, datetime, timezone

I use the HTML5 , activates the native datetime picker on iOS in a webapp.

I get this datetime string: "2013-08-25T11:49:18.353Z"
How can i parse it to my timezone and make it readable (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  It has the formatting you are after, and much much more.

```
moment("2013-08-25T11:49:18.353Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

In regard to time zones, you didn't really explain what you're after very well.  If you just mean to show this UTC time in the local time zone of the device running it, then the code above is exactly what you need.

However, if you are talking about displaying it in a *particular* time zone, then you should also look at the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) plugin, where you can do something like this:

```
moment("2013-08-25T11:49:18.353Z").tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working!

This is how i did it: http://jsfiddle.net/h4tFz/

```
    Date.prototype.format = function(format) //author: meizz
    {
      var o = {
        "M+" : this.getMonth()+1, //month
        "d+" : this.getDate(),    //day
        "h+" : this.getHours(),   //hour
        "m+" : this.getMinutes(), //minute
        "s+" : this.getSeconds(), //second
        "q+" : Math.floor((this.getMonth()+3)/3),  //quarter
        "S" : this.getMilliseconds() //millisecond
      }

      if(/(y+)/.test(format)) format=format.replace(RegExp.$1,
        (this.getFullYear()+"").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
      for(var k in o)if(new RegExp("("+ k +")").test(format))
        format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
          RegExp.$1.length==1 ? o[k] :
            ("00"+ o[k]).substr((""+ o[k]).length));
      return format;
    }

    alert(new Date("2013-08-25T11:49:18.353Z").format("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date=thestring.split("T")[0];
var year=date.split("-")[0];
var month=date.split("-")[1];
var day=date.split("-")[2];
var time=thestring.split("T")[1];
var hour=time.split(":")[0];
var minute=time.split(":")[1];
var second=time.split(":")[2].replace("Z","");
var formattedstring=day+"-"+month+"-"+year+" "+hour+":"+minute+":"+second
```

Comment: Timezone isn't correct and seconds are incorrect.

Used string "2013-08-25T11:49:18.353Z"
Response: "25-08-2013 11:49:18.353"